# How to disable automatic power-off on linux?

Tags: linux, power-management, shutdown, acpi

I need to disable the automatic power-off on shutdown so I can just withdraw the power myself. The reason for this is that the machine should power on itself when it gets power (which is accomplished by  Resume on Power Failure in BIOS).

I learned that I can turn off ACPI and APM by using the corresponding boot command options. Does this have any negative effect other than disabling standby etc.?

Is there another easy to accomplish solution for this problem (maybe using linux from a readonly partition and make sure all programs are closed before I withdraw the power)?

Comment: In what linux? For example in Debian there is no automatic power-off at all.

Comment: Hm, I was thinking of Ubuntu. If debian itself does it right I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `-H` instead of `-h` to `shutdown` will halt the system without powering down.

Comment: Can I change the default of Ubuntu to the behavior of -H?